# ip address validation for setting up open vps

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, network-interface, ethernet

I am following a tutorial to setup OpenVPN:

> To find and note down your IP address use this command  `ip a show
>   eth0` and get result
>
> ```
> inet 172.26.6.74/20 brd 172.26.15.255 scope global eth0
> ```

however I am getting error `Device "eth0" does not exist.`

I tried command `ip addr` and get this result

```
inet 192.168.43.288/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixrote wio1
```

This is the correct and required result?

Comment: sorry, now i follow the rule. Please help me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `ip a show eth0` can also be written as `ip addr show dev eth0`, which means "*show me the addressing for network device eth0*". When you get the error, `Device "eth0" does not exist.` it means that `eth0` is the wrong device name for your system.

You then tried `ip addr`, which can also be written as `ip addr show`, and will have listed the addressing for all devices on your system. I assume that in the result you showed us you had ignored the loopback device `lo0` and included just the one remaining device entry for `wio1`.

```
inet 192.168.43.288/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixrote wio1
```

So everywhere in your tutorial that references `eth0` you can probably substitute `wio1`. And everywhere in the tutorial that uses `172.26.6.74` you should use `192.168.43.288`.

If you were to edit your question to include a link to the tutorial it would be possible to check that there's nothing unexpected in it.